# I need to remove a class after adding it clicking on same checkbox, not the document

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm clicking on a checkbox to add some animation to a div, but when I want this animation to disappear I can only make it happen through $(document) click. Checkbox must add and then remove the class.

JS

```
 $('#inOrder').click(function(e) {
    $('.border').addClass('colorsborder');
    e.stopPropagation();

  $(document).click(function(e) {
    $('.border').removeClass('colorsborder');
  });

  });
  $('#inOrder').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

HTML

```
<input id="inOrder" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: "*when I want this animation to disappear*" - when do you want it to disappear? On a different interaction, after a set period of time, when the animation has finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may call [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method on the `jQuery` object (element) that you want to add or remove the class from. The method `toggleClass` will either:

- add the desired class when the element doesn't have it.
- or remove that class when the element has it already.

Here's a basic, live demo to illustrate the functionality:

```js
const checkbox = $('#inOrder'),
  relatedDiv = $('#related');

checkbox.on('change', () => relatedDiv.toggleClass('custom'))
```

```css
/** just for demo purpose */

#related {
  margin: 15px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#related.custom {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inOrder" type="checkbox" />
<div id="related">My appearnace will change on checkbox click</div>
```

> The above demo is pnly meant as a showcase of a possible solution that could be applied to your current problem and it **WON'T** do the exact thing you want to have unless you apply the required changes you need to suit your actual code/structuring.

Comment: Thank you! I understood in perfectly, but there is actually no need to make new const checkbox and relatedDiv, becuase I can just use the ID on html. If it's just for test, my bad :)

Comment: Hi @ArtemMilaw ! Glad you find my answer somehow helpful. As I said, I tried to give a *simple* demo that showcases my attempt to help you with your problem and invited you to build upon it or take it as a starting point. In the end, I cannot know what actually have, we only answer based on what you you post in your question. Anyway, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Then you want to toggle the class not add it when you click on checkbox

```
$('#inOrder').click(function(e) {
    $('.border').toggleClass('colorsborder');
....
```